# Select value from nested yaml

Tags: nested, yaml, key

I have this yaml file :

```
results:
  size: 1
  max-result: 1
  result:
  **- link:
      **href: https://bamboo.server/rest/api/latest/result/build-build-1-20****
      rel: self
    plan:
      shortName: build-1
      shortKey: build-1
      type: chain
      enabled: true
      link:
        href: https://bamboo.server/rest/api/latest/plan/build-build-1
        rel: self
      key: build-build-1
      name: IN - build
      planKey:
        key: build
    buildResultKey: build-build-1-10
    lifeCycleState: Finished
    id: 
    specsResult: 
---
```

I would like to output the link in bold which is on line 6

```
Output:
https://bamboo.server/rest/api/latest/result/build-build-1-20
```

how to?

Thank to all for our time

Comment: Does the file contain those stars and dashes?

Comment: Could you use a programming lang like python to do this?